# What should happen between a SAML SP timing out a session, and the IDP doing so?

Tags: spring, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I'm currently testing my SAML SP code against the SSOCircle IDP. The SP is currently set to timeout a login after 7200 seconds (2 hours); that is, if the user tries to authenticate 2 hours after they last did so, they need to enter their credentials into the IDP again, to get a new AuthnStatement that is within 2 hours before now.

However, the IDP has a different timeout. I'm not sure how long it is, but it's longer than 2 hours. What this means is that there's a window when the SP demands the user log in again, but the IDP will automatically use the same AuthnStatement anyway. This, of course, fails to validate. The way around this is for the user to manually go to SSOCircle and logout.

This seems awfully inconvenient. It would make more sense to me if the SP could redirect the user to re-enter their credentials at the IDP. But I have not seen anything in the documentation or online referring to this window. I can manually set `WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.maxAuthenticationAge` to match the IDP, but seems like a flimsy bandage.

I assume that all IDPs would perform similarly in this regard. Is that correct? What should the SP be doing differently during this window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I assume that all IDPs would perform similarly in this regard. Is that correct?

More or less, yes but this is not about how IdPs behave vs SPs. This is about the fact that the application session established by the SP is entirely separate from the SSO session established by the IdP. It's not about what *should* happen. It's about what you *want* to see. There are many scenarios where this use case proves annoying or great many others where this is perfectly acceptable. You need to decide what works for you.

> What should the SP be doing differently during this window?

If you wish to force the IdP to re-ask for credentials and disregard its own session, you may want to tag the authentication request sent to use `forcedAuthn=true`. The IdP should then challenge the user, assuming it supports SAML forced authentication requests.

Comment: Hmm... that would work, but that does mean losing the ability to auto-login to a service if you have very recently logged into another one, one of the benefits of SSO. So, if I understand correctly, I can't do what I want, so it's time to start balancing priorities.

Comment: No that's not what it means. You only ask for forcedAuthn when you need to. The request must be sent conditionally.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise you could do that, as I have only seen that option at bean creation time. That does sound much better.

Comment: Actually, I have been unable to find any way to activate forcedAuthN conditionally. It's either on or off for the entire run of the system. How do I make it conditional?

Comment: That depends on the SP. Since you dont mention what SP software you're using, and what version without any details, I cant answer that question. This is a feature of the SP, and some offer it and some dont.

Comment: I am writing my own, using the Spring SAML library. Effectively, I'm trying to implement that feature.

Comment: @AlbeyAmakiir may I know if you get answer for this post? I am having similar situation.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's been too long and I don't remember the specifics of what I did. But I had to make it myself.